# Get list of videos youtube api

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, forms, youtube-api

so I'm trying to create a web app that when you insert a search it gets the data from the youtube API using JSON and renders a list with the videos matching your search. When it retrieves it's getting some Letter and numerical answer but not a list of the videos. Any help in the right direction will be appreciated. This is the HTML for it:

```
     <div class="search-box-container">
     <form action="#" class="js-search-form search-box">
      <label for="query"></label>
      <input type="text" class="js-query search-form" placeholder="Search me">
      <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <h2>Results</h2>

  <div class="js-search-results">

  </div>
```

And this is the JS/Jquery for it:

```
  const YOUTUBE_SEARCH_URL = 
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';
`const key = 'key'//(hidden for privacy concerns);`

function getDataFromApi(searchTerm, callback) {
 const query = {
  part: 'snippet',
  key: key,
  q: `${searchTerm} in:name`,
 }
  $.getJSON(YOUTUBE_SEARCH_URL, query, callback);
}

function renderResult(result) {
 return `
  <div>
   <h2>
   <a class="js-result-name" href="http//www.youtube.com/watch?v=${ 
   result.id.videoId}" target="_blank">${result.id.videoId}</a></h2>
  </div>
 `;
}

function displayYoutubeSearchData(data) {
 console.log(data);
 const results = data.items.map((item, index) => renderResult(item));
 $('.js-search-results').html(results);
}

function watchSubmit() {
 $('.js-search-form').submit(event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const queryTarget = $(event.currentTarget).find('.js-query');
  const query = queryTarget.val();
  queryTarget.val("");
  getDataFromApi(query,displayYoutubeSearchData );
 });
}


$(watchSubmit);
```

[This is the answer that gets rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7VbR.png)

Comment: Can you post an example of the answer that you get?

Comment: Hi David, I posted the answer  I get when I search

Comment: @Gianina I guess you are already getting the links upon clicking it redirects to youtube isn't it?

Comment: @VineyHill not sure what I'm getting since upon clicking it redirects to 'not found'

Comment: What you are getting is *video id* for eg. RnBT9uUYb1w ---> _https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnBT9uUYb1w_ which is a valid video.So you need to just use them to make up the links.If you want to embed them instead then head to https://youtubevideoembed.com/ customize the way you want then use the html in your code.

Comment: exactly, I guess I am getting the video Id and what I'm trying to show is the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there: it is just a typo.

Look at the `href` attribute inside the template literal returned by the `renderResult()` method.

```
href="http//www.youtube.com/watch?v=${result.id.videoId}"
```

Mind the wrongly formed scheme (`http//` vs `https://`).

### A little bit of a context:

The YouTube API returns a collection of search results (i.e. an array of objects, `data.items` in your code) that match the query parameters specified in the API request.

Each item contains an `id` object with a `videoId` property. That is the "*alphanumeric answer*" you refer to in your question. After mapping `data.items` into an array of `result` HTML templates, you are reading that video id with `${result.id.videoId}`. Then you concatenate the YouTube *watch* URL with the video id.

You should check the JSON structure of the search result in the [YouTube Data API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search). Besides `id.videoId`, it contains more useful information. For example, you could prefer to show to the users the title of the video using `${result.snippet.title}` instead of the alphanumeric `videoId`.

Comment: Thank you that's what I'm trying to show, the title retrieved by the url. I guess it's probably retrieving the right ingo (videoId) but what I need is the title

Comment: @GianinaSkarlett - Did you get it? Are the links working? Did you get the title with `${result.snippet.title}`?

Comment: thank you so much! I did. Now I'm working on rendering the thumbnail with it!

Comment: @GianinaSkarlett - You are welcome! The thumbnails are in `${result.snippet.thumbnails}`. I think you can get the default one with `${result.snippet.thumbnails.default.url}`.

Comment: Thanks @David! I'll let you know how that goes!